# NLTK ConditionalFreqDist to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am trying to work with the table generated by nltk.ConditionalFreqDist but I can't seem to find any documentation on either writing the table to a csv file or exporting to other formats. I'd love to work with it in a pandas dataframe object, which is also really easy to write to a csv. The only thread I could find recommended [pickling the CFD object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150722/storing-conditional-frequency-distribution-using-nltk) which doesn't really solve my problem.

I wrote the following function to convert an nltk.ConditionalFreqDist object to a pd.DataFrame:

```
def nltk_cfd_to_pd_dataframe(cfd):
    """ Converts an nltk.ConditionalFreqDist object into a pandas DataFrame object. """

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for cond in cfd.conditions():
        col = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(dict(cfd[cond])))
        col.columns = [cond]
        df = df.join(col, how = 'outer')

    df = df.fillna(0)

    return df
```

But if I am going to do that, perhaps it would make sense to just write a new ConditionalFreqDist function that produces a pd.DataFrame in the first place. But before I reinvent the wheel, I wanted to see if there are any tricks that I am missing - either in NLTK or elsewhere to make the ConditionalFreqDist object talk with other formats and most importantly to export it to csv files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I went ahead and wrote a conditional frequency distribution function that takes a list of tuples like the `nltk.ConditionalFreqDist` function but returns a pandas Dataframe object. Works faster than converting the cfd object to a dataframe:

```
def cond_freq_dist(data):
    """ Takes a list of tuples and returns a conditional frequency distribution as a pandas dataframe. """

    cfd = {}
    for cond, freq in data:
        try:
            cfd[cond][freq] += 1
        except KeyError:
            try:
                cfd[cond][freq] = 1
            except KeyError:
                cfd[cond] = {freq: 1}

    return pd.DataFrame(cfd).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
pd.DataFrame(freq_dist.items(), columns=['word', 'frequency'])
```

Comment: Awesome one liner that beats the other answers here IMO.

Answer (score 6):

You can treat an FreqDist as a dict, and create a dataframe from there using from_dict

```
fdist = nltk.FreqDist( ... )    
df_fdist = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(fdist, orient='index')
df_fdist.columns = ['Frequency']
df_fdist.index.name = 'Term'
print(df_fdist)
df_fdist.to_csv(...)
```

output:

```
                      Frequency
Term
is                    70464
a                     26429
the                   15079
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice place to use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

def cond_freq_dist(data):
    """ Takes a list of tuples and returns a conditional frequency 
    distribution as a pandas dataframe. """

    cdf = defaultdict(defaultdict(int))
    for cond, freq in data:
        cfd[cond][freq] += 1
    return pd.DataFrame(cfd).fillna(0)
```

**Explanation:** a `defaultdict` essentially handles the exception handling in @primelens's answer behind the scenes. Instead of raising `KeyError` when referring to a key that doesn't exist yet, a `defaultdict` first creates an object for that key using the provided constructor function, then continues with that object. For the inner `dict`, the default is `int()` which is `0` to which we then add `1`.

Note that such an object may not pickle nicely due to the default constructor function in the `defaultdicts` - to pickle a `defaultdict`, you need to convert to a `dict` fist: `dict(myDefaultDict)`.